# SQL- unreadable special characters

Tags: unicode, turkish

I don't have much experience with MS SQL server 2008 R2 but here is the issue if you would help me please:
I have a table with a column/field (type : nvarchar) that stores text. The text is read from a text file and written to the database using vb.net application.
The text in the text file contains Turkish characters such as the u with 2 dots on top(in the future it will be in different languages )
When I open the table, the text in the column is not readable. It converts the Turkish special character to some unreadable characters. 
Is there anyway to make the text readable in the table?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't change any character stored in tables, I think the problem is displaying the text in different character set. Try using UTF-8 character set.